# Angular Karma not capturing browser

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner

I've an existing project on Angular 6 where tests not running. How it happens: in PhpStorm I press in context menu on file `run file.specs.ts`.

It starts test, opens the browser and nothing is happening then. Here is the log

```
Waiting for a captured browser... To capture a browser open http://localhost:9876/
14 10 2018 13:04:17.500:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
14 10 2018 13:04:17.799:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
14 10 2018 13:05:17.808:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
14 10 2018 13:05:18.055:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
14 10 2018 13:06:18.062:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
14 10 2018 13:06:18.199:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

How do I figure out what's wrong with these tests? I see no errors about dependencies or something else. Is there a chance to find what causes not capturing browser?

In this project all `spec.ts`s are missing (looks like someone's deleted them), so I try to run those which've been created on new components/services.

There is no such an option to start new project. I have to fix this one.

Any help will be very appreciated.

### This is my src/karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you write very simple(1=1) test and check whether its running or not. By using `fdescribe` or `fit` then you can understand either your configuration is wrong or your tests has issues.

Comment: Also have a look https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/154

Comment: Could your expand your answer? I'm not sure what you meaning while saying `fdescribe`. I'm new to testing. I'm using angular generated tests.

Comment: Also, I have another project where tests are working pretty fine. Dependencies look good as well as karma config

Comment: `it('should be one equal one')` prepending the character f with `it or describe` block will only execute that specific block of code. ex: `fit('should be one equal one')`

Comment: @Ntwobike as it was before. The browser is opened 3 times and closed. So it cannot capture the browser as I see. Meanwhile, exactly these settings work with another project tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was pretty simple and was shown by running `ng test`. There were some app-level errors which broke the Jasmine init (although I don't understand why it wasn't working when I tried to run test for a singe file in PhpStorm). So when I solved that problem my tests started working as well as singular tests (in browser they are shown to be run all)

Comment: I wonder why this kind of error doesn't get bubbled up. I had a missing module in mine that was causing this same problem. This solution worked for me.