# ng test not working and not connecting to the broswers

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

Hi I am trying to run ng test command in my project but ng test is not capturing the browser.

I have went through lot of stackoverflow answers but no luck.

Anyone have faced same issue?

I have tried this stack overflow.

[Angular Karma not capturing browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801608/angular-karma-not-capturing-browser)

My karma.config.js file is like this.

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 100000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance : 1,
    browserNoActivityTimeout : 60000,
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      thresholds: {
        emitWarning: true,
        global: {
            statements: 55,
            lines: 55,
            branches: 55,
            functions: 55
        }
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'local'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'junit', 'kjhtml'],
    // the default configuration
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'coverage', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: 'test-result.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
      nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "c",
  "version": "1.0.0-B162",
  "license": "C",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --aot --sourcemaps=true",
    "build": "ng build --aot --sourcemaps=true --output-hashing=all",
    "local-build": "ng build --env=local",
    "dev2-build": "ng build --env=dev2",
    "prod-build": "ng build --target production --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk",
    "test": "ng test",
    "code-coverage": "ng test -cc --browser Chrome",
    "lint": "ng lint --force --format checkstyle > ./coverage/tslint-result.xml",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "package-web": "cp .htaccess dist | tar -czvf spp-web.tar.gz -C dist .",
    "package-conf": "tar -czvf spp-conf.tar.gz -C httpd/ ."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.9",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.5.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jsencrypt": "^2.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.2",
    "primeng": "~5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.7",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.108",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-tslint-rules": "^1.0.4",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: are there any browser errors when you start the app with ng serve? What error are you getting when you do ng test?

Comment: @akhouri this was the error  \node_modules\@angular\cli\plugins\karma-webpack-throw-error.js:10:23)

Comment: \node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:61:14)

Comment: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.

Comment: Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.

Comment: Potentially, I have seen some async call playing up, which might cause this particular issue. I would suggest, you try running just one basic test (and probably comment out the rest). This will prove that your karma setup is fine. Then you can start debugging your test which has the issue from there.

Comment: In my test.ts I have added specific component only but still it's not working

Comment: You would need to create a angular app with your configuration in stackblitz or any js code sandbox to anyone reading your question to debug the config further.

Comment: @Bravo Did you ever get this fixed? I am having the same issue, the headless browser doesn't get launched.

Answer (score 1):

## Workaround solution

I saw the error when trying to run ng test.

```
+ ng test --code-coverage --watch=false
Your global Angular CLI version (11.2.3) is greater than your local version (10.1.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

05 03 2021 09:53:02.407:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.0.9 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
05 03 2021 09:53:02.410:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
05 03 2021 09:53:02.449:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
05 03 2021 09:53:14.287:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
    2021-03-05 09:53:02.740 Google Chrome[61832:635831] NSNotificationCenter connection invalid
[61841:775:0305/095302.753567:ERROR:gl_initializer_mac.cc(65)] Error choosing pixel format.
```

And I found my build server update chrome version 89.
Now I downgrade my chrome to version 86 and it works.